# Inserting values into sqlserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have inserted values into sql several times but now i am facing problem with the following code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(connstring);

        string name = txtName.Text;
        string user = txtUser.Text;
        string password = txtPwd.Text;
        string email = txtEmail.Text;
        long phone=Convert.ToInt64(txtPhone.Text);
        string address = txtAddr.Text;
        string city = txtCity.Text;
        string gender = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string dob = txtDOB.Text;
        string qualification = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string skills = CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        string insertstring = " insert into JobRegisteration values ("+name+","+user+","+password+","+email+","+phone+","+address+","+city+","+gender+","+dob+","+qualification+","+skills+")";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(insertstring,con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

When I am inserting values into this through asp.net page, its giving following error.

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'sbip'.
Invalid column name 'tttt'.
Invalid column name 'ttt'.
The multi-part identifier "tttttt@sss.ss" could not be bound.
Invalid column name 't'.
Invalid column name 'tttt'.
Invalid column name 'Male'.
Invalid column name 'MCA'.
Invalid column name 'C#'.
```

where tttt, male mca, etc etc are values that are passed from asp page.

thanks!

Comment: Try to use sql parameters. They are more secure and prevent some issues like bad input format, your error may related to this if values have commas or quotes or special characters like that. You can find examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Comment: Try put fields in sql explicitly i.e. "insert into JobRegisteration(field1_for_name, ..., field_for_skills) values (...)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your inserted values with `'` otherwise the database treat them as column names:

```
string insertstring = " insert into JobRegisteration values ('"+name+"','"+user+"','"+password+"','"+email+"','"+phone+"','"+address+"','"+city+"','"+gender+"','"+dob+"','"+qualification+"','"+skills+"')";
```

Also, as other suggested you really should rely on [Prepared Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx) to avoid such problems (among others).

Comment: prepared statements don't do a lot here; it is simply *parameterization* that is the essential bit; that is not quite the same thing

Answer (score 3):

use parameters like below and also `using` statements

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString;
// change this select statement based on your exact column names 
string insertstring = "insert into JobRegisteration ([Name] ,[User] ,[Password] ,[Email] ,[Phone],[Address] ,[City] ,[Gender] ,[Dob] ,[Qualification] ,[Skills]) values (@name ,@user ,@password ,@email ,@phone,@address ,@city ,@gender ,@dob ,@qualification ,@skills)";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(connstring))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(insertstring, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUser.Text);
    // give all the parameters..
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many solution to your problem.

1) Try to fit with this format:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

2) as said haim770, surround your values with '

3) use sql parameters way

4) or look at **Linq**, that's really simplify way to work with database

Answer (score 1):

You need to add single quote `'` in your query:

```
string insertstring = " insert into JobRegisteration values ('"+name+"','"+user+"','"+password+"','"+email+"','"+phone+"','"+address+"','"+city+"','"+gender+"','"+dob+"','"+qualification+"','"+skills+"')";
```

Answer (score 0):

use *using* (pun!), *bind variables* (a.k.a. parameters), format your query, when query seems dubious put what you want explicitly...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string name = txtName.Text;
  string user = txtUser.Text;
  string password = txtPwd.Text;
  string email = txtEmail.Text;
  long phone = Convert.ToInt64(txtPhone.Text); // <- what about +77(555)123-456-78?
  string address = txtAddr.Text;
  string city = txtCity.Text;
  string gender = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
  string dob = txtDOB.Text;
  string qualification = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
  string skills = CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem.ToString();

  using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString)) {
    con.Open();

    using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand()) {
      cmd.CommandText = 
        // replace all "field_for_*" for actual fields
        @"insert into JobRegisteration(
            field_for_name,
            field_for_user,
            field_for_password,
            field_for_email,
            field_for_phone, 
            field_for_address, 
            field_for_city, 
            field_for_gender, 
            field_for_dob, 
            field_for_qualification, 
            field_for_skills)
          values (
            @prm_name,
            @prm_user,
            @prm_password,
            @prm_email,
            @prm_phone, 
            @prm_address, 
            @prm_city, 
            @prm_gender, 
            @prm_dob, 
            @prm_qualification, 
            @prm_skills)";

       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_name", name);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_user", user);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_password", password);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_email", email); 
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_phone", phone);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_address", address);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_city", city);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_gender", gender); 
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_dob", dob);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_qualification", qualification);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_skills", skills);

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```